# How do I paste special from multiple workbooks to a master workbook

Tags: vba, excel, loops, paste

I'm trying to paste values from all files in a folder to a master folder but I keep getting errors in the paste process. This is my code:

```
    Sub LoopThrough()
Dim MyFile As String
    Dim erow
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim DestWB As Workbook
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook


    Set DestWB = ThisWorkbook


    FilePath = "C:\data\"
    MyFile = Dir(FilePath)


    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "Master.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If


    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & MyFile)
    Workbooks.Open (FilePath & MyFile)
    Range("A1:L51").Copy
    DestWB.Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 12)).PasteSpecial xlValues
    SourceWB.Close False
    MyFile = Dir
    Loop


    End Sub
```

Can I please get some help?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
DestWB.Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 12)).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Should be

```
DestWB.Sheets("Target Sheet").Range(DestWB.Sheets("Target Sheet").Cells(erow, 1), DestWB.Sheets("Target Sheet").Cells(erow, 12)).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

which can be re-written as

```
With DestWB.Sheets("Target Sheet")
    .Range(.Cells(erow, 1), .Cells(erow, 12)).PasteSpecial xlValues
End With
```

The point is that you need to qualify all `Range()` and `Cells()` methods with a worksheet and possibly workbook object when you aren't referring to the `ActiveSheet`

Also note that I've used `"Target Sheet"` but this should be changed to the name of the sheet you actually want to paste to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately i get an error 1004 on that row now. Do you know what that could be?

Comment: The message is on Swedish, but says like Error 1004: Program- or object defined error.